# Masstransit 8.1.1 with SignalR. What is the endpoint address for external clients?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, masstransit

Here's my services setup code in an ASP.Net Core application.

```
    var un = builder.Configuration.GetSection("NotificationService")["username"];
    var pass = builder.Configuration.GetSection("NotificationService")["password"];
    var host = builder.Configuration.GetSection("NotificationService")["host"];
    var port = 5672;

    builder.Services.AddMassTransit(config =>
    {
        config.AddSignalRHub<TenantHub>();
        config.AddConsumer<GroupProcessingResponseConsumer>();
        config.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host($"amqp://{un}:{pass}@{host}:{port}");

            cfg.AutoDelete = true;
            cfg.Durable = false;
            cfg.QueueExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            cfg.AutoStart = true;

        });

    });
```

This is the default in the documentation.  I cannot find anywhere how I send messages to the TenantHub from an external application -- mainly because I do not know what the connection URL is.   New to Masstransit; Do to the many updates and breaking changes in the framework, I cannot find good answers.

Using the MassTransit SignalR example,

```
   _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
       .WithUrl("http://localhost/tenantHub")
       .WithAutomaticReconnect()
       .Build();
```

This fails to connect.  I'm just missing something here.

Comment: You asked the same question on GitHub: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/4710